# Seperate Screen in Pygame like Playground Swift (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

[image: Playground Swift]

I want to separate the screen into 2 as in the picture in pygame. One screen is play game zone and another screen is for players to input. How can I do that?

Comment: Pygame just provides a graphics context and a game abstraction over an API such as OpenGL. If you want a UI, you will need to build it yourself using primitives in Pygame such as Sprite, Labels, etc... or you could use a GUI library such as Qt or Gtk which can also provide a OpenGL window alongside buttons, labels, textboxes, etc... that you can integrate into the application. But AFAIK, Pygame doesn't have much support for this.

Comment: Hi @jackw11111, thank you for your answer, do you know any ways I can use Sprite to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any built-in support for this; you'll have to implement this yourself. The principle is simple; just draw your menu to the left and your game to the right.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))

menu = pygame.Surface((50, 100))
game = pygame.Surface((50, 100))

menu.fill((255, 0,   0))  # Red
game.fill((0,   255, 0))  # Green

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    # Insert code that blits onto the menu and the game.

    screen.blit(menu, (0,  0))
    screen.blit(game, (50, 0))

    pygame.display.update()
```

The code above is a simple starter template. Simply draw/blit all your UI onto the `menu` surface, and all the game objects on the `game` surface. Then blit them to the different parts of the screen.

Comment: Thank you Ted, I will try to implement this way.